# How to correctly write rotation matrices by hand using glm::mat4?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, glm-math

I am writing an OpenGL program, and for that program, I am trying to write some rotation matrices by hand (I know about `glm::rotate`, but this is for a class, and so I cannot use that function), but it doesn't appear to be working like I am intending.

I am drawing a scene with a parking lot and car with tires drawn separately, and the tires are moving with the camera instead of staying put:
[image: car]
As you can see, the tires are rotated slightly in towards the camera, it looks like.

**EDIT**: In addition, it seems to skew other objects (that are rotated) when they are drawn:

[image: skewed]
Notice the highly skewed building.

As far as I understand, this is how rotation matrices are supposed to look:

[image: matrices]

And this is what I have done in code (parts about translation and scaling left out for brevity):

```
//glm::mat4 rotXMatrix = glm::rotate(rotation.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
glm::mat4 rotXMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
rotXMatrix[1][1] = cos(rotation.x);
rotXMatrix[1][2] = sin(rotation.x);
rotXMatrix[2][1] = -sin(rotation.x);
rotXMatrix[2][2] = cos(rotation.x);
//glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = glm::rotate(rotation.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
rotXMatrix[0][0] = cos(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[0][2] = -sin(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[2][0] = sin(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[2][2] = cos(rotation.y);
//glm::mat4 rotZMatrix = glm::rotate(rotation.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
glm::mat4 rotZMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
rotXMatrix[0][0] = cos(rotation.z);
rotXMatrix[0][1] = sin(rotation.z);
rotXMatrix[1][0] = -sin(rotation.z);
rotXMatrix[1][1] = cos(rotation.z);

glm::mat4 rotMatrix = rotZMatrix * rotYMatrix * rotXMatrix;
return posMatrix * rotMatrix * scaleMatrix;
```

It works correctly when I don't do it by hand (using `glm::rot` as shown in the commented out parts, so I'm wondering what I am misunderstanding about the way the rotation matrices are constructed. I am pretty sure that the order of the `[]`'s is correct, because I can hand-construct the matrices for translation and scaling using the same notation, and it correctly scales and moves the objects.

**EDIT**: Note that these transformation matrices are for the objects, and *not* the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the wrong matrices

```
glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
rotXMatrix[0][0] = cos(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[0][2] = -sin(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[2][0] = sin(rotation.y);
rotXMatrix[2][2] = cos(rotation.y);
```

You are constructing `rotYMatrix` but modify `rotXMatrix`.

Comment: Oh. Duh... Thank. I didn't realize I forgot to change the `X` to a `Y` then to a `Z`